# Is there any issue with iOS app store approval if I stored UUID in keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to get the same device identifier when the app is reinstalled. So from my research I got a conclusion that when I need to get something after app uninstallation I have to store it in the keychain. I decided to store **UUID** in the keychain. Now I want to know is there any problem with the app store approval if I stored **UUID** in the keychain. Also tell me if there is any other way to do this?

Comment: You cannot get the UDID anymore. What you do get, is identifierForVendor and you are free to do what you please with it. Just remember if you keep tracking this id across app installs, your actual identifierForVendor will mismatch with the saved one. [Read up on it here](http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/) if you want more info.

Comment: Ask that question when you successfully store a device UUID.

Comment: You can store a UUID in the keychain. I have an app on the store with multiple versions that have been through review that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an app on the store with regular updates in which I am storing device id in the keychain. And faced no issue from apple. Here is the Id I am talking about.

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
```

Comment: Can you confirm from your experience if the UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString does change and in what instances?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no problem with this, because actually you do not store the real UUID of the device. You are not able to access it since iOS 7. All you can store is just `identifierForVendor` which is unique for the device **and** your vendor account.

- UUID of device can be accessed only by owner of the device.
- `identifierForVendor` changes whenever you remove *every* app from the same vendor on the device.

Comment: Is he actually talking about the UDID? To me it sounds like he wants to generate a **UUID** (which he put in bold :-) and store that in the keychain (and that the keychain is persisted between reinstalls).

Comment: I am talking about UUID. Not UDID. @hnh